# Regex finds too many matches

Tags: regex

I think I almost got my Regex down now (thanks to this community). I have the following Regex:

```
== [A-Za-z\\s]+ ==
```

I am looking through text from Wikipedia, so this is how I'm going to split the text up after retrieval. An example:

```
== References == or == External Links ==
```

But some times I will get things such as:

```
=== Some thing === <-- This is not picked up. Great!
==== Some other Thing ==== <-- "== Some other Thing ==" is picked up. Bad!
```

I tried changing it to the following with no satisfactory result:

```
/^== [A-Za-z\\s]+ ==$/
(?<![\w\d])== [A-Za-z\\s]+ ==(?![\w\d])
/\b== [A-Za-z\\s]+ ==\b/
```

Any help with my regex?

Comment: I would help immensely if you told us what you wanted to match :-)  In English first perhaps?

Comment: Your regexp picks up anything between `==`. Why shouldn't it pick up `Some other Thing`?

Comment: Ahh, you want to match between `==` but not between `===`.

Comment: @Barmar I want to *only* match between == and nothing else.

Comment: ... or do you need to match as many ==== as there are?

Comment: I bet on the negative lookarounds. However, if they do not work, it might be because of the regex flavor which is used. In that case maybe add a tag to the question indicating which one should be considered for answering. sed, perl, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [negative lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to prohibit matching when there's an extra `=`.

```
(?<!=)== [A-Za-z\s]+ ==(?!=)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/DFJYQ4/1)

Comment: I think this might be it. I didn't know negative lookaround was a thing (Regex is basically black magic to me <.<). Give me a sec.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

`[=]+ [A-Za-z\\s]+ [=]+`

I know it does not make the 2 sides match, but it should pick up all instances now.

You can also change `[=]+` to `[=]{1,3}` if you need to limit it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the comments. If you want exactly == change the code from `[=]+` to `[=]{2}`.

Comment: What's the difference between `[=]{2}` and `==` as in his original regexp?

Comment: The problem he has is that matching exactly `==` doesn't preclude matching `===`, because the match starts after the first `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it with

```
(?<!=)==\s*([^=]+)\s*==(?!=)
```

See [**a demo here**](https://regex101.com/r/zq2gbx/2/).
This uses negative lookarounds and a negated character class.

---

Just for the sake of training purposes and to give you an alternative, you could use subroutines as well:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<left>(?<!=)(?==))
    (?<right>(?<==)(?!=))
    (?<separator>(?&left)==(?&right))

)
(?&separator)
(.+?)
(?&separator)
```

See a demo for [**this on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/8euCwE/1/) as well.